# Using Views with non-default constructors in Prism

Tags: vb.net, mvvm, unity-container, vb.net-2010

Afternoon,
I'm struggling at the moment to work out how I can create a view which requires a non default constructor (ie a constructor that requires input),

```
    Public Class Bootstrapper
    Inherits UnityBootstrapper

    Protected Overrides Function CreateShell() As System.Windows.DependencyObject
        Return New LogReader_Modular.Windows.Shell()
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub InitializeShell()
        MyBase.InitializeShell()
        Application.Current.MainWindow = CType(Me.Shell, Window)
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub ConfigureModuleCatalog()
        MyBase.ConfigureModuleCatalog()
        Dim moduleCatalog As ModuleCatalog = CType(Me.ModuleCatalog, ModuleCatalog)
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(GetType(GridModule))
    End Sub
....
....

Public Class GridModule
Implements IModule

Private ReadOnly regionManager As IRegionManager

Public Sub Initialize() Implements IModule.Initialize
    Try
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainDockingRegion", GetType(Views.GridModuleView))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("An Error occured the error was {0}", ex.ToString))
    End Try

End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal regionManager As IRegionManager)
    Try
        Me.regionManager = regionManager
    Catch ex As Exception
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("An Error occured the error was {0}", ex.ToString))
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

my issue is I want to pass in constructor values to GridModuleView, as its not really instantiated as such here, i dont really understand how I can pass in the values, any help with this would be appreciated as I've been looking at this for a few days now. EDIT * the data im wanting to pass in is coming from the shell and not the view, which is why i pasted the bootstrapper
Thanks
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(IRegionManager, String, Func(Object))` method instead of the `RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(IRegionManager, String, Type)` method and then pass the input from the shell to the GridModule.

Comment: You beat me to it.  the other overload of the method to do it.  public void Initialize()
{ 
    this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion",
            () => this.container.Resolve<EmployeesPresenter>().View);
}